# Comparativo entre años y mes

Tags: google-data-studio

estoy tratando de usar la combinación de datos, para poder generar un comparativo de el año actual vs el anterior, pero al generarlo no logro ubicarlos como en la primer imagen, es posible hacer esto en datastudio?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomendaría que mire https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask para qué tu pregunta sea mejor recibida,  haz el recorrido para entender como funciona obtener tu primera medalla https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges.

Answer (score 0):

tenes que tener un campo de fecha que puedas verlo como Fecha_mes (o la fraccion que quieras) y Fecha Año y ordenarlos por estos campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]